# Difference between CloudWatch Log Group, Stream and Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

On the AWS website, it states that the CloudWatch logs batch size is 1 MB (maximum). This quota can't be changed.

Can you explain what this means? Is a batch a **log group** or a **log stream**? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch in this context referrers to a **collection/set of log events** uploaded to CloudWatch Logs at once.

For example, instead of uploading log events to your log stream on one-by-one basis, you can upload **multiple events** at once using using AWS CLI [put-log-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-log-events.html). The collection of these multiple events is called a batch and its maximum size is 1 MB.

Uploading events in batches, saves you the **number of API requests** you would have to perform, when uploading individual events only.

Comment: Is this the same as a log stream then? AWS automatically creates streams, which are multiple events grouped together. Am I getting this correct?

Comment: @sjoelly Yes, "A log stream is a sequence of log events that share the same source. " from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CloudWatchLogsConcepts.html). So stream is a collection of log events. When you upload those events to the your stream you can do this is batches, of for example, 10 events at the same time.

Comment: Sorry one more question. Doesn't CloudWatch automatically create batches/streams? When you say "when you upload those events" what are you referring to? I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Most services will created them automatically. But you may be adding a custom logs stream to your application. For this you use [create-log-stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/create-log-stream.html) api call.